# how to specialize template member functions in template class?

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

For example:

```
template<unsigned number>
struct A
{
    template<class T>
    static void Fun()
    {}
};
```

And want to specialize A<1>::Fun()

```
template<>
A<1>::Fun<int>()
{
    /* some code here. */
}
```

doesn't work. How to do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you forgot to specify the return type of the function (`void`). Secondly, you need to have *two* `template<>`: one because you are explicitly specializing the class template, and one because you are explicitly specializing its member function template.

Therefore, this is the correct syntax:

```
template<> // Because you are explicitly specializing the A class template
template<> // Because you are explicitly specializing the `Fun()` member template
void A<1>::Fun<int>()
{
    /* some code here. */
}
```

Comment: Because A is a template too?

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: Exactly

Comment: @AndyProwl It works! I edited the question and it is more complex. Please help me to take a look? Thanks.

Comment: @user1899020: If it works and answers your question, then you should accept the answer. If you have a new question, then you should post a new question instead of editing the one which has already been answered :) This is the correct way of using StackOverflow

Comment: @AndyProwl I put the new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17503697/how-to-specialize-template-member-functions-in-template-class-already-specilzie . Thanks.